# How to achieve sequential animation in Material-UI(React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-animations

**My Component looks like this:-**

Essentially what i want to achieve is , the left most div should come up first and then after some delay the second and so forth...Currently all divs are appearing at the same time.I tried using 'nth-child' but couldn't achieve the desired effect.

My doubt is if i am applying the 'nth-child' syntax currently.If not then how to achieve this in MUI environment.

```
const Feature = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
    
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
    const domRef = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) =>{
            entries.forEach(entry => setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting))
        })
         observer.observe(domRef.current)
         return () => observer.unobserve(domRef.current) //cleanup
    }, [])

  return (
        <Container maxWidth='lg'>
            <Grid container justifyContent='center' spacing={1}>
                {data.map((d, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={3} className={classes.gridItem} key={d.id}>

//
**// This is the individual item div for which I want to achieve the animation.**
//
                            <div
                                className={`${classes.item} ${isVisible ? classes.animate : ''}`}
                                ref={domRef}
                            >
                                <SvgIcon component={d.icon} className={classes.icon} />
                                <Typography variant='h5' color='initial' className={classes.title}>
                                    {d.title}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography
                                    variant='p'
                                    color='textSecondary'
                                    className={classes.desc}
                                >
                                    {d.desc}
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                            <Hidden mdDown>
                                {index !== 3 && (
                                    <Divider
                                        orientation='vertical'
                                        style={{ height: '70%', marginLeft: '25px' }}
                                    ></Divider>
                                )}
                            </Hidden>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                })}
            </Grid>
        </Container>
  )
}

export default Feature
```

My Styles.jsx files looks like this:-

```
    '@keyframes move-up': {
        '0%': { opacity: '0', transform: 'translateY(30px)' },
        '100%': { opacity: '1', transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
    },
    gridItem: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    animate: {
        animation: '$move-up 1s ease-in-out',
    },
    item: {
        height: '200px',
        width: '250px',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        '$item:nth-child(1)': {
            animationDelay: '1s',
        },
        '$item:nth-child(2)': {
            animationDelay: '2s',
        },
        '$item:nth-child(3)': {
            animationDelay: '3s',
        },
        '$item:nth-child(4)': {
            animationDelay: '4s',
        },
    },
```

[this is the current effect for the above mentioned code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr1iX.gif)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `&:nth-of-type`, not `&:nth-child`. The child selector targets the children components (`SvgIcon`, `Typography` etc), which are not animated.

Also this will only work if the `.item` div has no div siblings other than `.item`s. Which means, `Hidden` and `Divider` must not be divs.

Comment: Thanks ,i commented out the Hidden and Divider and made changes to css( nth-of-type in place of nth-child) but still have the same effect.